# smbclient -M nt_status_bad_network_name error

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, server-message-block, windows-8, host

I am trying to send a test message (for a test project) from my `Ubuntu Virtualbox Guest` to my `Windows 8 host`. I am getting the error `nt_status_bad_network_name error`.

What I know that works:

I can ping from Host to Guest and vice versa by using computer host name. MSG Service (replace net send) is enabled on `Windows 8` side.

NOTE: 
For LAN testing purposes, I did disable Windows firewall (thus is how I can ping from Ubuntu to Window host)

So I wonder why I type `smbclient -M "computername`" in the terminal from the virtualbox guest OS, I get "`nt_status_bad_network_name error`" when I try to send the message to the Windows host?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put whole command line and smbclient response, so please make sure that `"computername"` contains heading `\\` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

In my case if I change `\\DESKTOP-3GBJJ5E\Users\zhong\Desktop\` to `\\DESKTOP-3GBJJ5E\Users\` I can get rid of `NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE`.

So the login command is

```sh
smbclient '//192.168.232.216/Users/zhong/Desktop/xitiz/' -U zhong -W
```